# Socket.io: server needs 2 connections for the fitst one to respond

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I try to make a private chat(or group chat) with socket io. To try the concept I made an array "person" which contains the username and the room they should join. The checks if the user exists are non-existent and are an extension in the future.

The problem that I'm having is that if user1 connects he can't send a message until user2 connects. user 2 only can send a message when user3 connects. They can all send if I restart my server.

Any clue what I could be doing wrong?

Should be noted that broadcast works, so I doubt that the server config would be the issue

Server:

```
let numUsers = 0;
let person = {user1: "1", user2: "1",user3: "2", user4: "2", user5: "1",user6: "3"};

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("conn");
    let addedUser = false;

    // when the client emits 'add user', this listens and executes
    socket.on('add user', function (username) {
        //if (person[username]) {
        // we store the username and room in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        socket.room = person[username];
        console.log(socket.room);
        socket.join(socket.room);

        ++numUsers;
        addedUser = true;
        socket.to(socket.room).emit('login', {
            numUsers: socket.room
        });
        // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
        socket.to(socket.room).emit('user joined', {
            username: socket.username,
            numUsers: numUsers
        });
        //}
    });

    // when the client emits 'new message', this listens and executes

    socket.on('new message', function (data) {
        console.log(" room:" + socket.room + ";user:"+ socket.username + ";data:" +data);
        // we tell the client to execute 'new message'
        socket.to(socket.room).emit('new message', {
            username: socket.username,
            message: data

        });
    });
    // // when the client emits 'typing', we broadcast it to others
    // socket.on('typing', function () {
    //     socket.to(socket.room).emit('typing', {
    //         username: socket.username
    //     });
    // });
    //
    // // when the client emits 'stop typing', we broadcast it to others
    // socket.on('stop typing', function () {
    //     socket.to(socket.room).emit('stop typing', {
    //         username: socket.username
    //     });
    // });
    //when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        if (addedUser) {
            --numUsers;


            socket.to(socket.room).emit('user left', {
                username: socket.username,
                numUsers: numUsers
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Client:

```
$(function() {
var FADE_TIME = 150; // ms
var TYPING_TIMER_LENGTH = 400; // ms
var COLORS = [
   '#e21400', '#91580f', '#f8a700', '#f78b00',
   '#58dc00', '#287b00', '#a8f07a', '#4ae8c4',
   '#3b88eb', '#3824aa', '#a700ff', '#d300e7'
 ];

 // Initialize variables
 var $window = $(window);
 var $usernameInput = $('.usernameInput'); // Input for username
 var $messages = $('.messages'); // Messages area
 var $inputMessage = $('.inputMessage'); // Input message input box

 var $loginPage = $('.login.page'); // The login page
 var $chatPage = $('.chat.page'); // The chatroom page

 // Prompt for setting a username
 var username;
 var connected = false;
 var typing = false;
 var lastTypingTime;
 var $currentInput = $usernameInput.focus();

 var socket = io();

 function addParticipantsMessage (data) {
   var message = '';
   if (data.numUsers === 1) {
     message += "there's 1 participant";
   } else {
     message += "there are " + data.numUsers + " participants";
   }
   log(message);
 }

 // Sets the client's username
 function setUsername () {
   username = cleanInput($usernameInput.val().trim());

   // If the username is valid
   if (username) {
     $loginPage.fadeOut();
     $chatPage.show();
     $loginPage.off('click');
     $currentInput = $inputMessage.focus();

     // Tell the server your username
     socket.emit('add user', username);
   }
 }

 // Sends a chat message
 function sendMessage () {
   var message = $inputMessage.val();
   // Prevent markup from being injected into the message
   message = cleanInput(message);
   // if there is a non-empty message and a socket connection
   if (message && connected) {
     $inputMessage.val('');
     addChatMessage({
       username: username,
       message: message
     });
     // tell server to execute 'new message' and send along one parameter
     socket.emit('new message', message);
   }
 }

 // Log a message
 function log (message, options) {
   var $el = $('<li>').addClass('log').text(message);
   addMessageElement($el, options);
 }

 // Adds the visual chat message to the message list
 function addChatMessage (data, options) {
   // Don't fade the message in if there is an 'X was typing'
   var $typingMessages = getTypingMessages(data);
   options = options || {};
   if ($typingMessages.length !== 0) {
     options.fade = false;
     $typingMessages.remove();
   }

   var $usernameDiv = $('<span class="username"/>')
     .text(data.username)
     .css('color', getUsernameColor(data.username));
   var $messageBodyDiv = $('<span class="messageBody">')
     .text(data.message);

   var typingClass = data.typing ? 'typing' : '';
   var $messageDiv = $('<li class="message"/>')
     .data('username', data.username)
     .addClass(typingClass)
     .append($usernameDiv, $messageBodyDiv);

   addMessageElement($messageDiv, options);
 }

 // Adds the visual chat typing message
 function addChatTyping (data) {
   data.typing = true;
   data.message = 'is typing';
   addChatMessage(data);
 }

 // Removes the visual chat typing message
 function removeChatTyping (data) {
   getTypingMessages(data).fadeOut(function () {
     $(this).remove();
   });
 }

 // Adds a message element to the messages and scrolls to the bottom
 // el - The element to add as a message
 // options.fade - If the element should fade-in (default = true)
 // options.prepend - If the element should prepend
 //   all other messages (default = false)
 function addMessageElement (el, options) {
   var $el = $(el);

   // Setup default options
   if (!options) {
     options = {};
   }
   if (typeof options.fade === 'undefined') {
     options.fade = true;
   }
   if (typeof options.prepend === 'undefined') {
     options.prepend = false;
   }

   // Apply options
   if (options.fade) {
     $el.hide().fadeIn(FADE_TIME);
   }
   if (options.prepend) {
     $messages.prepend($el);
   } else {
     $messages.append($el);
   }
   $messages[0].scrollTop = $messages[0].scrollHeight;
 }

 // Prevents input from having injected markup
 function cleanInput (input) {
   return $('<div/>').text(input).html();
 }

 // Updates the typing event
 function updateTyping () {
   if (connected) {
     if (!typing) {
       typing = true;
       socket.emit('typing');
     }
     lastTypingTime = (new Date()).getTime();

     setTimeout(function () {
       var typingTimer = (new Date()).getTime();
       var timeDiff = typingTimer - lastTypingTime;
       if (timeDiff >= TYPING_TIMER_LENGTH && typing) {
         socket.emit('stop typing');
         typing = false;
       }
     }, TYPING_TIMER_LENGTH);
   }
 }

 // Gets the 'X is typing' messages of a user
 function getTypingMessages (data) {
   return $('.typing.message').filter(function (i) {
     return $(this).data('username') === data.username;
   });
 }

 // Gets the color of a username through our hash function
 function getUsernameColor (username) {
   // Compute hash code
   var hash = 7;
   for (var i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {
      hash = username.charCodeAt(i) + (hash << 5) - hash;
   }
   // Calculate color
   var index = Math.abs(hash % COLORS.length);
   return COLORS[index];
 }

 // Keyboard events

 $window.keydown(function (event) {
   // Auto-focus the current input when a key is typed
   if (!(event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey || event.altKey)) {
     $currentInput.focus();
   }
   // When the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
   if (event.which === 13) {
     if (username) {
       sendMessage();
       socket.emit('stop typing');
       typing = false;
     } else {
       setUsername();
     }
   }
 });

 $inputMessage.on('input', function() {
   updateTyping();
 });

 // Click events

 // Focus input when clicking anywhere on login page
 $loginPage.click(function () {
   $currentInput.focus();
 });

 // Focus input when clicking on the message input's border
 $inputMessage.click(function () {
   $inputMessage.focus();
 });

 // Socket events

 // Whenever the server emits 'login', log the login message
 socket.on('login', function (data) {
   connected = true;
   // Display the welcome message
   var message = "Welcome to Socket.IO Chat – ";
   log(message, {
     prepend: true
   });
   addParticipantsMessage(data);
 });

 // Whenever the server emits 'new message', update the chat body
 socket.on('new message', function (data) {
   addChatMessage(data);
 });

 // Whenever the server emits 'user joined', log it in the chat body
 socket.on('user joined', function (data) {
   log(data.username + ' joined');
   addParticipantsMessage(data);
 });

 // Whenever the server emits 'user left', log it in the chat body
 socket.on('user left', function (data) {
   log(data.username + ' left');
   addParticipantsMessage(data);
   removeChatTyping(data);
 });

 // Whenever the server emits 'typing', show the typing message
 socket.on('typing', function (data) {
   addChatTyping(data);
 });

 // Whenever the server emits 'stop typing', kill the typing message
 socket.on('stop typing', function (data) {
   removeChatTyping(data);
 });

 socket.on('disconnect', function () {
   log('you have been disconnected');
 });

 socket.on('reconnect', function () {
   log('you have been reconnected');
   if (username) {
     socket.emit('add user', username);
   }
 });

 socket.on('reconnect_error', function () {
   log('attempt to reconnect has failed');
 });

});
```

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Socket.IO Chat Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul class="pages">
  <li class="chat page">
    <div class="chatArea">
      <ul class="messages"></ul>
    </div>
    <input class="inputMessage" placeholder="Type here..."/>
  </li>
  <li class="login page">
    <div class="form">
      <h3 class="title">What's your nickname?</h3>
      <input class="usernameInput" type="text" maxlength="14" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed the issue by replacing all `socket.to(socket.room).emit` by

`io.sockets.to(socket.room).emit` on the server side, client side nothing needs to be changed